# How to create a pre-release nuget package using version number from the assembly

Tags: .net, azure-devops, continuous-integration, nuget, devops

I am trying to create a Nuget Package using azure devops. I want to create a pre-release version of a package before a stable release is created.Currently am trying to package an .netstandard 2.0 app.

What i have tried -

Tried to set version in csproj - `<Version>1.0.6-alpha</Version>` . This actually works but am not sure how can this alpha tag be removed when i want to promote it to a stable version

I want the package to take the version from the assembly (not use auto versioning ) for example if the assembly version is 1.0.0 i need a package that is 1.0.0-alpha and later 1.0.0 when its moved to production . I can see many solutions online that uses preset version numbers (in the variables tab) and appending build number etc but i am looking for a way that can use the version from assembly itself and not custom defined. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/nuget?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#package-versioning) is the link which explains package versioning

Below is the pipeline that i have tried

[image]

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT sorry am just trying this out now. Looks like the versioning works. But am trying to find out how to create the nupkg file in the artifacts directory. Its now getting created in bin and so artifact publish job cannot find it .

Comment: You just need to add another argument `--output` to specify the artifacts directory:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack#arguments

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT yea i got it to work by using --output $(system.artifactsdirectory) . Is this the right directory to use? i got this by checking where the nuget pack command packs the file and mapping it to system variables.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Please confirm the directory ($(system.artifactsdirectory) ) i have used is correct to create nuget packages

Comment: If you are in the build pipeline, the directory should be `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, the default folder for task `Publish build artifacts` is `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Great thanks is there any reference articles on which directory should be used where . from the current pipeline looks like artifactsdirectory and ArtifactStagingDirectory are pointing to the same location

Comment: Check the document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to create a pre-release nuget package using version number from the assembly

Since you are trying to package an `.netstandard 2.0` app, we could use the `dotnet pack`, the version is pulled from the project definition (previously `project.json`, now `*.csproj`), not the assembly `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

From the [project.json to csproj migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj#version) docs, you can use the `VersionPrefix` and `VersionSuffix` properties in the project file `.csproj`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <VersionPrefix>1.0.0</VersionPrefix>
  <VersionSuffix>alpha</VersionSuffix>
</PropertyGroup>
```

According to your request:

> `if the assembly version is 1.0.0 i need a package that is 1.0.0-alpha and later 1.0.0 when its moved to production`

To resolve this issue, I set the value of `VersionSuffix` is `null`, so, it is:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <VersionPrefix>1.0.0</VersionPrefix>
  <VersionSuffix></VersionSuffix>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then we use the `DotNetCoreCLI` [custom donet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack) task instead of `nuget pack` task with argument `--version-suffix "alpha"`:

[image]

The result is:

[image]

In this case, we could generate package version is `1.0.0-alpha` when the assembly version is `1.0.0`.

On the other hand, we could remove the argument `--version-suffix "alpha"` when its moved to production:

[image]

Now, This should be all you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i ll try this out.  For now i got it to work by having a task that reads the version from the csproj but this looks like a better solution. What about .Net framework projects  . i have some .net framework projects thats needs to be converted as well

Comment: @Karthik，For .net framework you just need to use powershell scripts to parsing .cs file to get the version.  If you have any question about .net framework, you could open a thread about it, I will keep follow up.

Comment: can you please take a look at my another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61285765/unable-to-index-one-or-more-source-files-for-symbols-file

Comment: There is an existing issue mentioned by Ben Vaughan on Microsoft's developer community site: "there is no way to set the VersionPrefix property via the Visual Studio UI (Project Properties -> Package -> PackageVersion). Manually updating the project file to have a VersionPrefix rather than a Version element works fine, and displays correctly in the Project Properties form, however subsequent edits to the field via the UI results in an unmodified VersionPrefix element, and a newly created Version element which then stops the "dotnet pack" command from applying the VersionSuffix."

Answer (score 1):

`NuGet.exe` is mainly used to pack `nuspec` files.

When working with the modern `csproj` format, things like version is specified using MSBuild properties, if it's specified it'll override what's set in the `csproj` i.e. from the command line using .NET CLI.

`dotnet pack /p:Version=VERSIONNUMBER` (or launching MSBuild with `pack` target).

In a Azure DevOps Pipeline task you can enter it by in the ".NET CLI" task using pack command and specifying additional options
[image: Additional pack options]

But recommended use is automated build versioning using, preferable using build number (build number can be set from configuration, scripts or inferred using tasks like i.e. GitVersion, using build number will give traceability)

[image: Automatic packaging versioning]

Comment: Thanks for then info. I was trying to get the version already specified in the csproj and append a tag like "beta" to it . So if am pushing an assembly of version 5.0.0 it will create a package like "MyAssembly.5.0.0-beta.nupkg"