# Unable to index one or more source files for symbols file

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, nuget, azure-artifacts

I am trying to create Nuget packages and push it to azure artifacts. Am using `Index sources and publish symbols` to publish symbols to the azure symbol server. But i keep getting this warning

> Unable to index one or more source files for symbols file
>   'D:\a\1\s\MyClassLibrary\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\MyClassLibrary.pdb'.

I have tried setting debug type to full but still the same. I also tried packing PDB in to the nuget package itself but still it cant find the source code even though visual studio shows the symbols are loaded

> Loaded
>   'C:\Users\UserName.nuget\packages\myclasslibrary\2.0.15\lib\netstandard2.0\MyClassLibrary.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded.

I cant find any articles that explains this in depth .

Am using the below arguments for dotnet pack command after which the publish symbol task metioned above is executed

```
--output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) --include-symbols --include-source -v d -c Debug --version-suffix "alpha" -p:SymbolPackageFormat=snupkg
```

[image: dotnet pack]

[image: Publish Symbols]

Comment: I failed to reproduce above issue. Can you share more details about your pipeline's configuration and some sample code? Any steps we can take to reproduce above warning?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT It is a netstandard2.0 class library. Updated question with snapshot of  pack and publish symbol step. Also here is the log of publish symbols step https://pastebin.com/Mc1C4fqV

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT any luck reproducing this ?

Comment: Sorry still cannot reproduce above warning. I created a simple netstandard project and used the same tasks in above screenshots. The publish symbols task succeeded without warning `Unable to index..`.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT Any way i can get the app so i can try it on my account and cross check the configurations